# Does netlogo dbscan extension work for patches?

Tags: netlogo

Does the netlogo dbscan (kmeans) clustering (by location) extension work for patches as well as turtles? Or does it work for only turtles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation is pretty clear that it's for turtles. Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to do? Clustering algorithms identify areas of more or less density. So spatial clustering is meaningless for patches. However, clustering-by-variable is meaningful, but not available.

If you want to cluster by some patch variable, why not simply create a turtle for every patch that has whatever patch variable you want to cluster by, and then cluster those turtles and transfer the cluster information back to their patches? This code demonstrates the approach but doesnt do anything with the clustering information.

```
extensions [dbscan]

patches-own [wealth]
turtles-own [wealth-here]

to testme
  clear-all
  ask patches [set wealth one-of [50 200 500]]
  ; let clusters dbscan:cluster-by-variable patches "wealth" 3 20 ; this generates error
  ask patches [sprout 1 [set wealth-here wealth set size 0]]
  let clusters dbscan:cluster-by-variable turtles "wealth-here" 3 20 ; this works
  show clusters
end
```

Comment: Thanks @JenB I figured that out a while back so I had to overhaul my code, but got it done! Thanks!